# c# / wpf simulate arrow keys (and other control keys) through events

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am attempting to simulate several keyboard actions in a wpf textbox, including arrow presses (to move caret etc) from another event (e.g. a button click). I have no problem with adding text by raising the

`TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent`

event, but attempting to send keys through Keyboard events is not working:

```
Keyboard.Focus(targetTextBox);

KeyEventArgs ke = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(targetTextBox), 0, Key.UP);

ke.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
targetTextBox.RaiseEvent(ke);
```

Is there a way to send control keys through the TextInputEvent, or making the Keyboard event work - i have tried using previewDownEvent and pairing with keyUp events.

EDIT: Also i would prefer to do this through wpf if possible, without using windows forms.

Thanks

Comment: That's strange, but your code works fine on my machine with WPF 3.5 and 4.0

Comment: The code seems to work for everything except cursor keys, which is what I need to move the caret.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) is what you're looking for, though it doesn't use events.

```
...
    SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}");
    SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
...
```

Remember to set focus to the control you want to input in first.

Comment: I would prefer to do it through wpf if possible, Is there a solution that doesn't require windows forms?